# How to perform bitwise or operation between two binary numbers in Swift?

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

I need to do bitwise OR of two binary strings.

For example, if the binary strings are "110001" and "101101", then I need the result as "111101".

How can I do this in Swift ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert it first into `Int`

```
let a = Int("110001", radix: 2)!
let b = Int("101101", radix: 2)!
let c = a | b

let stringResult = String(c, radix: 2, uppercase: false)
```

More info:

- [Int init(_:radix:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2924481-init)
- [String init(_:radix:uppercase:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me how can I do this for very big binary string. For example a binary string like this : "1001101111101011011100101100100110111011111011000100111100111110111101011011011100111001100011111010". Current solution can't convert this number which is pretty long.

Comment: you will want to iterate over the characters in both of your input strings and if either character is `"1"` then you would write `"1"` to the output string, otherwise you would write `"0"`. Iterating both strings at the same time can be achieved with `zip` assuming both input strings are the same length.

Comment: @SalehMasum That string is 100 char long, what would it represent? Maybe you should divide it into smaller chunks first before converting it.

Comment: @theoriginalbit yes it is achievable by a for loop but the problem is it takes too long that's why I am looking for alternatives. A BigInteger class can do this job but swift does not have it.

Comment: @SalehMasum when you say "takes too long" what exactly is your definition of "too long". I was able to just perform a measure with a 500 char long string and it took an average of 0.005 seconds.

Comment: Also there are libraries for Swift that do BigInt, with this being the first result in searching https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-BigInt it even has a `BInt.init(_,radix:)` initialiser the same as `Int`.

Comment: @theoriginalbit I have an array of 500 binary string each 500 bits of length. I need to perform a permutation of these 500 items and each time perform an or operation and find out number of 1's in the result. In that case it takes too long.

Comment: @SalehMasum I think you should post that problem into another question, because the way we see it, it will works very fast (less than a second), so maybe there is a problem with your code.